# Trac component(s) referencing separate GIT repositories

Tags: git, trac, repository

We have a large project that encompass several sub-projects with their separate GIT repositories, which we are all looking to bring into Trac to help better manage the project as a whole.  My question;  Is it possible to reference their respective (separate) repositories from within Trac's component system?  I've done some research into the Git plugins available, but don't know which one to pick, hoping for some guidance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need separate Trac environments for each Git repository? Or do you want to have one Trac environment for multiple Git repositories?

For the latter, starting with Trac 0.12, Trac gained multi-repository support, which allows to integrate multiple repositories in one Trac environment. The current [GitPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/GitPlugin) supports this mode of operation as well. You might want to give it a try, but try not to enable any of GitPlugin's caching features for the mean time, as they've been known to cause problems at the moment (but it's being worked upon).

PS: I'm the author of GitPlugin

Comment: I'd like to have one Trac Repository with multiple git repositories.  Thanks I'll have a look at GitPlugin, and see whether I can tie it to a repository.

Answer (score 0):

I've moved across to Redmine, as I felt it was more flexible in allowing subprojects and repositories to be attached to those.  Also as my work involves many seperate projects, I didn't want to set up new instances of TRAC for each project.